# SAPUI5 - mockup server

Tags: sapui5

I'm following this [Mockup Server tutorial](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/bae9d90d2e9c4206889368f04edab508.html) for SAPUI5. But I'm not able to retrieve the data and set it to my model. Here's what I do:

I have slightly changed the data so, so two things have to be changed:

- json data - *Person.json*:

  { "id":1, 
  "first_name":"Chris", 
  "last_name":"Johnston", "email":"cjohnston0@dailymotion.com", "gender":"Male", "ip_address":"119.220.205.173" }
- *emphasized text*

``

```
<edmx:Edmx Version="1.0"
xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx"/>
<edmx:DataServices m:DataServiceVersion="1.0"
m:MaxDataServiceVersion="3.0">
xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">

<Schema Namespace="PersonsData" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/09/edm">
        <EntityType Name="Person">
            <Key>
                <PropertyRef Name="id"/>
            </Key>
            <Property name="id" Type="Edm.Int16" Nullable="false" />
            <Property Name="first_name" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="40" FixedLength="false" Unicode="true"/>
            <Property Name="last_name" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="40" FixedLength="false" Unicode="true"/>
            <Property Name="email" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false"/>
            <Property Name="gender" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="40" FixedLength="false"/>
            <Property Name="ip_address" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="40" FixedLength="false" Unicode="true"/>
        </EntityType>
    </Schema>
    <Schema Namespace="databinding.PersonsData.Model" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/09/edm">
        <EntityContainer Name="PersonEntities" m:IsDefaultEntityContainer="true" p6:LazyLoadingEnabled="true"
            xmlns:p6="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/annotation">
            <EntitySet Name="Persons" EntityType="PersonsData.Invoice"/>
        </EntityContainer>
    </Schema>
</edmx:DataServices>
```

The SAPUI5 Web IDE says that `edmx` namespace does not exist.

[image]

So I went to check [edmx namespace](http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx) and it does not exists.

Chrome developer tools reports the same error:

[image]

Could this be the problem?

I checked and `mockserver.init()` is triggered.

Did Microsoft moved this namespace somewhere? Cause I was not able to find it.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

what I see is that you messed up your XML structure. As the error says your XML is invalid.

- You've closed the surrounding *edmx:Edmx* tag at the beginning of the document
- You've closed the *edmx:DataServices* tag too early

Furthermore the attribute *name* of the property *id* is in lowercase. Try to make an uppercased *Name*.

Try to use this xml:

```
<edmx:Edmx Version="1.0" xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx">
<edmx:DataServices m:DataServiceVersion="1.0" m:MaxDataServiceVersion="3.0"
    xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
    <Schema Namespace="PersonsData" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/09/edm">
        <EntityType Name="Person">
            <Key>
                <PropertyRef Name="id"/>
            </Key>
            <Property Name="id" Type="Edm.Int16" Nullable="false"/>
            <Property Name="first_name" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="40" FixedLength="false" Unicode="true"/>
            <Property Name="last_name" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="40" FixedLength="false" Unicode="true"/>
            <Property Name="email" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false"/>
            <Property Name="gender" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="40" FixedLength="false"/>
            <Property Name="ip_address" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="40" FixedLength="false" Unicode="true"/>
        </EntityType>
    </Schema>
    <Schema Namespace="databinding.PersonsData.Model" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/09/edm">
        <EntityContainer Name="PersonEntities" m:IsDefaultEntityContainer="true" p6:LazyLoadingEnabled="true"
            xmlns:p6="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/annotation">
            <EntitySet Name="Persons" EntityType="PersonsData.Invoice"/>
        </EntityContainer>
    </Schema>
</edmx:DataServices>
```